# How to communicate with a flask server (backend) to send it information from a react native frontend?

Tags: flask, react-native

I'm developing an application with a react native frontend and a flask backend.
I managed to retrieve information from the flask server via a local url but I don't know **how to communicate in the other direction and send information to the flask server**.
I need to communicate with the backend and send the information that the user will provide to the application. I work with an android emulator (Android Studio).

What I did :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const serverUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:5000/data"

class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            information: null,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(serverUrl)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                this.setState({
                    information: data.data,
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error))   
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{this.state.information}</Text>
            </View>
            
        )
    }
}
...
```

and

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/data')
def get_data():
    return {"data": "monument"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: You want to send an HTTP POST from React Native, using fetch(), and with a separate endpoint on Flask side.

Comment: Yes @Alex, I want to communicate with the flask server from my react native application.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the fetch function by modifying it like so:

```
fetch("http://10.0.2.2:5000/send", {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },

  //make sure to serialize your JSON body
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: "John Doe",
    password: "john123"
  })
})
.then((response) => { 
    console.log(response);
   //do something here with the response from the flask server
});
```

You should also add another route with a method to handle this request in Flask. You can do it like so:

```
@app.route('/send', methods=['POST']) #GET requests will be blocked
def send():        # you can do something here with the data sent
    return "Data received in server successfully!"
```

> Here's an [article](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/processing-incoming-request-data-in-flask/amp) that provides more information on handling post requests in Flask.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I get an error, I explained it below.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sahith Kurapati for your response.

I did it like this.
But I got an error on the url page `http://localhost:5000/send`.

**Internal Server Error : The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.**

Here's the flask code :

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/data')
def send_data():
    return {"data": "monument"}

@app.route('/send', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return "Data received in server successfully!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

And here's the react native code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const serverUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:5000/data"

class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            information: null,
        };
    }

    _sendData() {
        fetch("http://10.0.2.2:5000/send", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: "John Doe",
                password: "john123"
            })
        })
            .then((response) => { 
                console.log(response);
                console.log("ok");
            //do something here with the response from the flask server
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(serverUrl)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                this.setState({
                    information: data.data,
                });
                this._sendData();
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error))   
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{this.state.information}</Text>
            </View>
            
        )
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem :

```
req = {}

@app.route('/send', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_data():
    global req
    if request.method == 'POST':
        req = request.get_json()
        print(req)
        return req
    else:
        return "Data received in server"
```